# DRF: ModelSerializer for nested JSON data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to convert my existing DJANGO app to API based. I have done the front-end in Angular and working on the backend now. The data from client is going to be in json format as below

```
  {
    "title": "wue",
    "author": "asd",
    "addons": {
                "header":"head",
                "footer":"foot"
              }
  }
```

I have written the **model.py**

```
class BookDetails(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    author= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    addons= models.ForeignKey(Addons, null=True)
class Addons(models.Model):
    header= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    footer= models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class AddonsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Addons
        fields = ('header', 'footer')
        depth = 2


class BookDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addons = AddonsSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BookDetails
        depth = 2
        fields = ('title', 'author','addons')
```

**views.py**

```
class BookDetailsList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        stocks = BookDetails.objects.all()
        serializers = BookDetailsSerializer(stocks, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = BookDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my **urls.py** is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^bookdetails/', views.BookDetailsList.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Now when I'm using postman to send the data then the *addons* field is not getting populated, it gets *null* value.

I have tried to write a custom create but I think somewhere I'm messing it up, but not able to figure out where.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tracks_data = validated_data.pop('addons')
    addons = BookDetails.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Addons.objects.create(addons=addons, **tracks_data)
    return addons
```

it gives me an error that

> KeyError at /bookdetails/ 'addons'

I have tried assigning **depth=2** but it is not working. what is that I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 1 (removed read_only=True)** still no luck:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/backend/publishbook/views.py", line 19, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/backend/publishbook/serializers.py", line 26, in create
    Addons.objects.create(addons=addons, **tracks_data)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/argo/Django/pagination-backend/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 443, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'addons' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding book details as addon to addon model itself, try updationg your code like this,

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('addons')
        addons = Addons.objects.create(**tracks_data)
        book = BookDetails.objects.create(addons=addons, **validated_data)
        return book
```

Comment: Seems I was doing it wrong. Followed your advice and it started to work. But converting foreignkey relation to onetoone was the main trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have `read_only=True` specified in your `addons` field in your `BookDetailsSerializer`. This prevents the addons part of the json dictionary being passed to your `create` method. That's why there's a KeyError on your attempt to `pop` (I guess, although if you pasted your stacktrace rather than just the error it would help).

Other than that, I'm not sure about your `create` method - perhaps you could reformat it so the variable names are more meaningful. You still have the `tracks_data` from the DRF example, and you've named the product of your `BookDetails` create 'addons' - which doesn't really make sense and makes it hard to read. Also, could you specify which serializer the `create` method is part of, as it's hard to tell just by looking at it.

Note: In general it's conventional to give Django model names singular form, so yours would be BookDetail and Addon.

---

Update after question edit:

Now you have an error on this line: `Addons.objects.create(addons=addons, **tracks_data)`.
The error is telling you that `addons` is not a valid field on the `Addons` model. I think it would work just to do `Addons.objects.create(**tracks_data)`.

Comment: I have removed the read_only but still there is error. And yes I would rename all the variables once I have a working code

Comment: That is a different error. so we're making progress. About the variable naming, I am suggesting that it would be easier for me and others to help you if your variables were named more sensibly. If you don't want to take that advice, you may find it harder to get good help on this website.

Comment: Ok. I would rename it accordingly and update my answer

Comment: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table publishbook_bookdetails has no column named addon_id` when i'm removeing _addons=addons_

Comment: That is telling you that your database is not in sync with your models as they are posted above. Perhaps you haven't done a migration.

Comment: Well, the database is telling you that the field doesn't exist, and it's not lying. In any case, your initial problem has been solved and we're now debugging your project, so I suggest you post another question for this specific problem. I think if you just spend some more time reading and understanding the concepts of Django models and DRF serializers you will gain a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143308/discussion-between-arghya-saha-and-chidg).

Answer (score 0):

I think its your create method you need to rectify.
You've got a Bookdetails model with a ForeignKey to Addon model.
From my point of view, the code should be something like this,
(You should remove read_only=True, Obviously)

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tracks_data = validated_data.pop('addons')
    book_details = BookDetails.objects.create(**validated_data)
    addons = Addons.objects.create(**tracks_data)
    book_details.addons = addons
    book_details.save()
    return book_details
```

Hope you got what were you looking for.

Seriously, you need to re-consider about your naming conventions.